# Django Python inserting queryset into dictionary come with tag (<>). How to remove tag?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-queryset

'I'm trying to make dictionary with content list as it value. Problem here is while inserting in dictionary it comes with a tag.

```
shades =  Shade.objects.filter(shade_code__contains=search_text)
colorListDict = {}

for color in shades:
        colorListDict[color.color_one] = []
        colorListDict[color.color_one].append(color.color_quantity)
print colorListDict
```

Result:

```
{<Color: Blue MTR>: [Decimal('4.000')], <Color: Yellow 2GL>: [Decimal('0.390')], <Color: Orange RL>: [Decimal('1.500')], <Color: Brown GRL>: [Decimal('5.000')], <Color: DarkViolet>: [Decimal('2.700')], <Color: Red SG>: [Decimal('1.000')], <Color: Violet B>: [Decimal('1.000')], <Color: Red 10B>: [Decimal('2.000')], <Color: Dark Violet RL>: [Decimal('20.000')], <Color: TBlue>: [Decimal('1.050')], <Color: Blue 2R>: [Decimal('1.900')], <Color: Yellow 4GL>: [Decimal('2.100')], <Color: Grey SBL>: [Decimal('1.250')], <Color: Blue 5G>: [Decimal('1.200')]}
```

I want it to be like:

```
{'Blue MTR': [4.000], 'Yellow 2GL': [0.390], 'Orange RL': [1.500], 'Blue 5G': [1.200]}
```

Comment: serialize the queryset, then you dont have to explicitly create the dictionary

Comment: Use serializers that will make it a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

For just an example you could serialize the queryset,

```
from django.core import serializers

shades =  Shade.objects.filter(shade_code__contains=search_text)
serialized = serializers.serialize(queryset=shades, format='json')
```

Answer (score 0):

`color.color_name` and `color.color_quantity` are not simple strings. They are objects, that is why you are seeing the object enclosed in angle brackets. You have to find the appropriate string representations and print that.

Try to find the object definitions in order to do this.